# Pass entire value using ID in URL stateparam

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am successful in passing one parameter which is ID in the url using `$stateparams` . Now I want to pass entire value related to that ID using stateparams so that I can fetch values in the next state.

This is my **view** from where I am passing ID value:-

```
<div class="td-table" ng-repeat="vms in load_all | filter: Search">
   <div class="info-body"  ui-sref="chart({itemId: vms.ID})">
```

I want to pass entire value of `vms`.

My **state**:-

```
url: '/chart/{itemId}',
params : {
  obj : null  
        }
```

Passing value from state 1 **controller** :-

```
$scope.ListAnswer = function(itemId) {
$state.go('chart', {itemId: itemId});
   };
```

Receiving ID on another state 2 **controller** :-

```
 $scope.informations = $stateParams.itemId;
    console.log($scope.informations);
```

I am unable to pass entire `vms` value .

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass '**vms**' object in `$state.go` to the 2nd controller

```
$scope.ListAnswer = function(itemId, vms) {
    // pass vms to obj here
    $state.go('chart', {itemId: itemId, obj: vms});
};
```

In your state you have to define params like this,

```
.state('stateName', {
    url: '/chart/{itemId}',
    params: { obj : null },
    /* ... */
});
```

Then in state 2 controller, you can receive entire `vms` object using

```
$stateParams.obj
```

Comment: getting undefined in console. Is there any changes to make in state ?

Comment: @WhoAmI, Can u check what is the value of vms inside `ListAnswer` function, also I have updated my answer

Comment: How can I check ?  `ListAnswer` is not in any event. And my state is same that I had posted.

Comment: `ListAnswer` is the function you call from 1st controller right, which goes to the next state, you might be calling that function from somewhere

Comment: No, it is from the first controller from where I am passing the data.

Comment: Yes, In the first controller only you have data for **vms** right